# Sound not ringing on load of The Intent

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, soundpool

I am calling this class from another class using intent and i want to play this song "song.ogg" on load of the class .. please Help me How To??

```
public class DetlsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detls_layout);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        SoundPool soundPool;
        int soundID;
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundID = soundPool.load(this,R.raw.song, 1);
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        //soundPool.play(soundID,1f,1f,1,0,1f);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ringing Song",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("song.ogg");
        soundPool.load(assetFileDescriptor,1);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Played",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("LOGCAT","Exception Song");
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception in LogCat ?

Comment: No i m not getting any exception,, so is this code correct??

Comment: i m getting this toast "Ringing Song" but not the toast "played"

Comment: Do you want to play song.ogg or R.raw.song ??

Comment: i have made a folder raw In res and have put a file named song.ogg in taht folder. and i want to play that file ..

Comment: is there any permission to be taken or registration to be done in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int soundID;
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Ringing Song",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        soundID = soundPool.load(this,R.raw.song, 1);
        int waitLimit = 1000;
        int waitCounter = 0;
        int throttle = 10;
        while(soundPool.play(soundID, 1.f, 1.f, 1, 0, 1.f) == 0 && waitCounter < waitLimit)
          {waitCounter++; SystemClock.sleep(throttle);}
        Toast.makeText(this,"Played "+soundID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("LOGCAT","Exception Song");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Exception "+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Replace your code with above code. Current code give warning **soundpool sample 1 not ready** so check this using while condition.

Here, your resource is in raw folder that's why we use `soundID = soundPool.load(this,R.raw.song, 1);`. If your resource is in assets folder at that time you can use `soundID = soundPool.load(getAssets().openFd("song.ogg"),1);`